# Xcode 6 Vector App Icons

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode6

At WWDC, I faintly remember them saying that with Xcode 6, you could use a vector image for your app icon.  It may have been that, or they said that you could use one png size for all of the icons.  Has anyone figured out how to use this?

Comment: I've seen answers about xcode auto-generating asset images at @1x,@2x,@3x from a vector, but not app icons.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Digging through the Xcode 6 UI, there doesn't appear to be a way to do this.

When you create a new image asset, there's an option to set the type of the asset to 'vector'.

[image]

This option doesn't appear for AppIcon or LaunchImage assets, so I conclude this isn't possible.